# How to set timer for 1 hour to check network every 1 hour?

Tags: android, timer, alarmmanager

i want to check network every 1 hour to update data to database from local storage but don't know which one to use either timer or alarm.if you have any code please share with me,thanks is advance.

Comment: Try to create intent service to check inter connection is available or not. And if connection is available notify to receiver and update data in  background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GcmNetworkManager](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmNetworkManager), it fits the need you described, [here](https://github.com/filipproch/gcmnetworkmanager-android-example) is a working sample. It uses JobScheduler internally above 21, and below 21 it uses some Google propriety. You can schedule a periodic task to be run every one hour while adding a pre-condition that internet is required for your task to run. The system will then determine a proper time to run you task. Something like this,

```
PeriodicTask periodicTask = new PeriodicTask.Builder()
            .setService(YOUR_SERVICE) //should extend GcmTaskService
            .setPeriod(TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(1))
            .setFlex(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(30))
            .setTag("UpdateDB")
            .setRequiredNetwork(PeriodicTask.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTED)
            .setPersisted(true)
            .build();
```

[here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/optimize-battery-life-with-androids-gcm-network-manager/) is a good article explaining the different functionalities provided by GCMNetwork Manager

Answer (score -1):

use background `Service` and use `CountDownTimer` in your `Service` class. and set interval of 1 hour in `CountDownTimer`